# What event is for when app is already open?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have a `Page_Load` event which contains the code I want executing every time the user opens the application. However, when a user clicks the back button on their Windows device, the application is still open, so when they go onto the application the `Page_Load` event is not called.

I've also tried an `OnNavigatedTo` event:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
   InitialStartOfApp();
 }
```

But the `InitialStartOfApp()` doesn't get called. I know it doesn't get called because I try debugging the line, however it isn't executed.

Does anyone know any events that would resolve this or any ideas?

The `Page_Load` event is this:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  InitialStartOfApp();
}
```

Comment: If your application is not made "dormant", it is simply restored in the state it was before the user navigated out of the app (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). So you don't have any control there...

Comment: @TimBourguignon So theres absolutely no way to call the method when the user navigates back to the running app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need handle the [Application.Resuming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.resuming%20Application.Resuming) event that is raised when the apps continues after a previous suspension.

```
Application app = Application.Current;
app.Resuming += App_Resuming;
...

private void App_Resuming(object sender, object e) {
   InitialStartOfApp();
}
```

Comment: On `App app = App.Current;`  I get an error `Cannot implicity convert type Windows.UI.Xaml.Application to MyApp.App are you missing a cast?`